# datagridview - visible/read only property cannot be set on a specific data column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datasource, readonly, visible

I have a datagridview in an application.  The datagridview has a datatable as its datasource.

After filling the datagridview, I have a procedure that sets column properties (width, visible, readonly).

This process works in my dev environment.  However, in my production environment I get this message:

**Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function.**

I have narrowed the issue down to this code at the point Visible = False:

```
        For i As Integer = 0 To D.Columns.Count - 1
            D.Columns(i).Width = 50
            D.Columns(i).DefaultCellStyle.Alignment=DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
            D.Columns(i).Visible = False
        Next
```

The error only occurs on Column 1.  However, if I exclude Column 1 from being made not Visible, the application fails when I set Column 1 to read only.

I understand the reentrant call error is due to an infinite loop because the datagridview cell is being used.  However, the code works in dev.  I am using a copy of the dev database in production testing so the problem should not be data related.

What would cause the reentrant call when a column is made not visible or readonly?

Comment: You are looping through every column and setting the property of each column. So if you have it set to false, well your going to hide them all...

Comment: I hide them all then make three of them visible.  The issue is that it fails when setting the second column invisible, before it gets to the other eight columns.

Comment: Where do you make them visible, I dont see that...?

Comment: Three are made visible in code that follows what I show above.  I am redesigning the datagridview backend now because I think some of my problems were caused by issues there.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is, instead of looping through each of the columns in the datagridview, loop through the columns in the source datatable and make the datagridview column for the source column, invisible using the column name instead of index.  Indices can shuffle (when fiddling with properties), names stay the same unless you change them.

I have come up against similar road blocks before.

Comment: I changed to loop through the source datatable for the column names, and it fails on the same column.  It does not fail in dev but on the production machine.                          D.Columns(col.ColumnName).Visible = False

Comment: I think I have a workaround whereby after everything on the form is loaded, I click on a button to run the datagridview formatting.

I'm not sure why this works, but it does separate the load action from the formatting action.